# Stuck at reify:babel-runtime: timing reifyNode:node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y Completed in 80067ms While creating react app

Tags: reactjs

c:\react>create-react-app my-app
Creating a new React app in c:\react\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

[##################] - reify:babel-runtime: timing reifyNode:node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y Completed in 80067ms

It got stuck at this point for ages....Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue, after several try and with stuck command prompt I just switched to vscode terminal and tried installing it from there and guess what it just worked!
Pls try vscode terminal or any other terminal to install create-react-app and it should work.